# Injecting a Diesel connection into an Iron middleware

Tags: rust, iron, rust-diesel

In writing my tests, I'd like to be able to inject a connection into the request so that I can wrap the entire test case in a transaction (even if there is more than one request in the test case).

I've attempted to do this using a `BeforeMiddleware` which I can link in my test cases to insert a connection, as such:

```
pub type DatabaseConnection = PooledConnection<ConnectionManager<PgConnection>>;

pub struct DatabaseOverride {
    conn: DatabaseConnection,
}

impl BeforeMiddleware for DatabaseOverride {
    fn before(&self, req: &mut Request) -> IronResult<()> {
        req.extensions_mut().entry::<DatabaseOverride>().or_insert(self.conn);
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

However, I'm encountering a compile error in trying to do this:

```
error: the trait bound `std::rc::Rc<diesel::pg::connection::raw::RawConnection>: std::marker::Sync` is not satisfied [E0277]
impl BeforeMiddleware for DatabaseOverride {
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
help: run `rustc --explain E0277` to see a detailed explanation
note: `std::rc::Rc<diesel::pg::connection::raw::RawConnection>` cannot be shared between threads safely
note: required because it appears within the type `diesel::pg::PgConnection`
note: required because it appears within the type `r2d2::Conn<diesel::pg::PgConnection>`
note: required because it appears within the type `std::option::Option<r2d2::Conn<diesel::pg::PgConnection>>`
note: required because it appears within the type `r2d2::PooledConnection<r2d2_diesel::ConnectionManager<diesel::pg::PgConnection>>`
note: required because it appears within the type `utility::db::DatabaseOverride`
note: required by `iron::BeforeMiddleware`

error: the trait bound `std::cell::Cell<i32>: std::marker::Sync` is not satisfied [E0277]
impl BeforeMiddleware for DatabaseOverride {
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
help: run `rustc --explain E0277` to see a detailed explanation
note: `std::cell::Cell<i32>` cannot be shared between threads safely
note: required because it appears within the type `diesel::pg::PgConnection`
note: required because it appears within the type `r2d2::Conn<diesel::pg::PgConnection>`
note: required because it appears within the type `std::option::Option<r2d2::Conn<diesel::pg::PgConnection>>`
note: required because it appears within the type `r2d2::PooledConnection<r2d2_diesel::ConnectionManager<diesel::pg::PgConnection>>`
note: required because it appears within the type `utility::db::DatabaseOverride`
note: required by `iron::BeforeMiddleware`
```

Is there a way around this with diesel's connections? I've found several examples on Github to do this using the `pg` crate, but I'd like to keep using diesel.

Comment: I could be wrong (I'm not near my Rust environment atm) but don't you have to implement a `typemap` trait or something similar to be able to store it in the request extensions?

Comment: Yes, I have one implemented (I didn't post it here for brevity). The issue here is that I can't initialize a `BeforeMiddleware` with a `diesel::pg::PgConnection` because `PgConnection` doesn't implement `Sync`. I was hoping someone knew of a workaround to this limitation.

Comment: Having not used `diesel` myself I'm not sure. However, the fact it uses any of the `Cell` types or even an unsynchronized smart pointer like `Rc` will cause it to automatically fail the ability to implement `Sync`.

Answer (score 7):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38014778/321731) will certainly solve the problem, but it's not optimal. As mentioned, you can't share a single connection as it's not thread safe. However, while wrapping it in a `Mutex` makes it thread-safe, it would force all the server threads to use a *single* connection. Instead, you want to use a connection pool.

You can accomplish this with the [r2d2](https://crates.io/crates/r2d2) and [r2d2-diesel](https://crates.io/crates/r2d2-diesel) crates. This will establish multiple connections as needed, and reuse them when possible in a thread safe manner.

Answer (score 3):

Since there isn't enough code provided for me to reproduce your issue, I've made this:

```
use std::cell::Cell;

trait Middleware: Sync {}

struct Unsharable(Cell<bool>);

impl Middleware for Unsharable {}

fn main() {}
```

which has the same error:

```
error: the trait bound `std::cell::Cell<bool>: std::marker::Sync` is not satisfied [E0277]
impl Middleware for Unsharable {}
     ^~~~~~~~~~
help: run `rustc --explain E0277` to see a detailed explanation
note: `std::cell::Cell<bool>` cannot be shared between threads safely
note: required because it appears within the type `Unsharable`
note: required by `Middleware`
```

You can solve the problem by changing the type to make it cross-thread compatible:

```
use std::sync::Mutex;

struct Sharable(Mutex<Unsharable>);

impl Middleware for Sharable {}
```

Note that Rust has done a **very good thing for you**: it prevented you from using a type that is unsafe to be called in multiple threads.

---

> In writing my tests, I'd like to be able to inject a connection into the request so that I can wrap the entire test case in a transaction (even if there is more than one request in the test case).

I'd suggest that it's possible an architectural change would be even better. Separate the domains of "web framework" from your "database". The authors of [*Growing Object-Oriented Software, Guided by Tests*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321503627) (a highly recommended book) advocate for this style.

Pull apart your code such that there is a method that simply accepts some type that can start / end a transaction, write the interesting stuff there, and test it thoroughly. Then have just enough glue code in the web layer to create a transaction object, then call the next layer down.